# Plot frequency of dataframe value per year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains hourly temperature data from 1990-2019 for 25 different locations. I want to count the amount of hours that a value is above or below a certain threshold and then plot that amount as a sum of the hours for every year. I know I can use a bar chart or histogram to plot, but am unsure how to aggregate the data to perform this task.

Dataframe:

```
time                 Antwerp       Rotterdam  ...
1990-01-01 00:00:00  2             4          ...
1990-01-01 01:00:00  3             4          ...
1990-01-01 02:00:00  2             4          ...
...
```

Do I need to use the groupby function?

Sample data to demonstrate:

```
time                    Antwerp Rotterdam   Los Angeles
0   1990-01-01 00:00:00 0       2           15
1   1990-01-01 01:00:00 1       4           14
2   1990-01-01 02:00:00 3       5           15
3   1990-01-01 03:00:00 2       6           16
```

Now I am looking for the amount of hours that one city is equal to or less than 5 degrees during the year 1990. Expected output:

```
time    Antwerp Rotterdam   Los Angeles
1990    4       3           0
```

Ideally I would want to be able to select whatever temperature value I want.

Comment: Just create a boolean column that is True if the treshold condition is True. Then you can groupby(year).sum over the bool col.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `DatetimeIndex`, compare, e.g. for greater by [`DataFrame.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) and then count `True`s values by aggregate `sum`:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df = df.set_index('time')

N = 2
df = df.gt(N).groupby(df.index.year).sum()
print (df)
      Antwerp  Rotterdam
time                    
1990      0.0        1.0
1991      1.0        2.0
```

If want low or equal use [`DataFrame.le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.le.html):

```
N = 3
df = df.le(N).groupby(df.index.year).sum()
print (df)
      Antwerp  Rotterdam
time                    
1990      1.0        0.0
1991      2.0        0.0
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what this code is doing. I want to be able to count all the values below or above a certain threshold during each year. For example, in the tiny dataframe snippet, the count equal to or below 3 would be 3 for Antwerp and 0 for Rotterdam. Does this make sense?

Comment: @EliTurasky - Can you create some sample data with expected output?  thanks

Comment: I didn't realize what gt or le meant. This is doing what I need! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is without using pandas functions.

```
# get the time column as a list by timelist = list(df['time'])
def get_hour_ud(df, threshold):
    # timelist = list(df['time'])
    # df['time'] = ['1990-01-01 00:00:00', '1990-01-01 01:00:00', '1990-01-01 02:00:00'] # remove this line
    timelist = list(df['time'])
    hour_list = [int(a.split(' ')[1].split(':')[0]) for a in timelist]
    up_cnt = sum(a>threshold for a in hour_list)
    low_cnt = sum(a<threshold for a in hour_list)
    print(up_cnt)
    print(low_cnt)
    return up_cnt, low_cnt
```